# GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddExplosionForce in Unity Doesn't Work

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a little game in Unity, with Stickybombs. I made it so that when you press Right Click, the stickybomb blows up, destroys itself, and instantiates a particle effect for explosions. Here is the following code:

```
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2")) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddExplosionForce(explosionForce, transform.position, explosionRadius, 3.0f);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Instantiate (Explosion, transform.position, new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }

}
```

However, the line GetComponent().AddExplosionForce(explosionForce, transform.position, explosionRadius, 3.0f); doesn't do anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the variables. Thanks in advance :D

```js
public GameObject Explosion;
private float explosionForce = 300;
private float explosionRadius = 15f;
```

Comment: `Force can be applied only to an active rigidbody. If a GameObject is inactive, AddExplosionForce has no effect.` http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce.html has about the same procedure as your code. Your code seems fine to me, how do you know that that line doesn't do anything? Is it not affecting other rigidbodies, from which you made sure are not non-kinematic? Did you try playing with the `isKinematic` in that script or extended the explosion radius / force to higher values?

Comment: Thanks for your input @MaximilianGerhardt All rigidbodies that I am trying to affect with the explosion are Active, and non-kinematic. I made the Radius and Force values 5000f, to no avail.

Comment: Here is the picture for one of the rigidbody Components of the crate http://www.mediafire.com/view/icbfykvgppv1is0/THingy.png

Comment: Try to call AddExplosionForce with an upwardsModifier vector to lift them visibly into the air, or additionaly use the ForceMode VelocityChange, sothat it ignores the mass of the object. Maybe a force is beeing applied but in the wrong direction? You can try to extensively log the value of GetComponent<Rigidbody>.velocity and position every frame to see if there are some minor changes.

Comment: Using methods you said, Nothing happened. The crates didn't change position, ever slightly. I made the upwardsModifier a high number, but it didn't work. I even made ForceMode.VelocityChange, and it still doesn't work. No change.

Comment: Don't know if it can help, but you destroy the object as soon as AddExplosionForce is invoked. This way, you don't have the time to simulate the explosion effect, because the object is immediately destroied. Have you tried by removing the Destroy() call and see what happpens?

Comment: @Andrea THANKS :D I fell so stupid. The though occured to me but I didn't check. That was the problem. Thank you so much :D

Comment: @Flygamer101: Happy to help! I've converted my comment into an answer. Please, accept it since you solved the issue! And no need to feel stupid at all, it happened to me many times :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*My previous comment, converted into an answer:*

Don't know if it can help, but you destroy the object as soon as `AddExplosionForce` is invoked. This way, you don't have the time to simulate the explosion effect, because the object is immediately destroied. Have you tried by removing the `Destroy()` call and see what happpens?

*Side note:* I suggest to call the `Destroy()` function at the end, and using a delay, as an example.